# Why is visibility not working on a div?

Tags: css, html

Here is my html:

```
<div class="form3">
<form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Text Here...">
    <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.form3 { visibility: hidden; }
```

I tried to remove div and apply class directly to the form element, but that didn't work either.

Comment: This is not possible. Please check any css overwrite to `.form3`.

Comment: Which browser are you in?

Comment: Use style="display: none;"

Comment: check this fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/6bLs3cgn/ `visibility: hidden; ` working fine here. Double check your code and css

Comment: make sure your css is correctly embedded.

Comment: I can see your 'form3' div ending not properly, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good enough to work. Make sure that you have included the css file correctly. If you have, you might have overwritten .form3 class somewhere which is causing this problem.

Try using :

```
.form3 { visibility: hidden !important; }
```

If this doesn't work either, try clearing your browsers cache and reload again.